# mySQL TIMEDIFF Query to JS var - Error because of colons

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, var

How can I pass the results of my MySQL Query using TIMEDIFF to a Javascript var in the same PHP file? I want to use the result as a text string label. I get a browser error because of the colon in the passed data.

MySQL:

```
$mytimediff = 'TIMEDIFF(NOW(), DBTimeStamp) as myTimeDiff';        
$querylast = "SELECT *, $mytimediff FROM user_log ORDER BY LogID DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultlast = mysql_query($querylast);
$rowtimediff = $rowlast['myTimeDiff'];
```

JS:

```
var rowage = <?php echo $rowtimediff ?>;
```

This results in the browser console error:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Console error output example showing the colons: 
"var rowage = 00:00:43;"

All other MySQL operations and variables pass ok.

Comment: You need to enclose `$rowtimediff` in quotes inside `<?php echo $rowtimediff ?>` i.e.  `<?php echo '$rowtimediff' ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json-encode a PHP variable when printing if you want to use it in Javascript.

```
<?php
    $rowtimediff = ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2, 'baz' => 3];
?>
<script>
    var rowage = <?= json_encode($rowtimediff) ?>;
    console.log(rowage);
</script>
```

As a result, you will get a valid Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var rowage = {"foo":1,"bar":2,"baz":3};
    console.log(rowage);
</script>
```

Additionally, when working with strings, you can simply wrap that PHP injection in quotes (numbers doesn't require quotes) like that:

```
var rowage = "<?= $rowtimediff ?>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your JS code try to wrap the php code with double quote like this

```
var rowage="<?php cho $rowtimediff; ?>";
```